# Is it possible to dynamically insert an Ember Component into text?

Tags: ember.js

I have a helper that--at the moment--simply converts markdown formatted text into proper html. In addition to that, I want to pass it a pair of text indexes. The text between these indexes will be sliced out, plopped into a component, and then reinserted. The user will then be able to click on that text and interface with it like it was that component.

The problem is, I have no idea how (or if it's even possible) to insert a component into text that's being processed by a helper. For that matter, is it possible to do at all, even outside of a helper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, it sounds like what you may be looking for is a view or component, rather than a helper. A helper is a lower-level piece of functionality which is invoked towards the end of the rendering process. It is quite isolated in terms of what it can access or do. Ember helpers (in contrast to pure Handlebars helpers) are quite sure that their job is to insert a stream of HTML text into a view's buffer. For instance, you cannot easily capture the text returned from a helper and decide to do something else with it. You certainly cannot build views or invoke components from within the helper. To put it a different way, by the time a helper is called, you are far past the point in the Ember control flow where it wants to be creating components or other view-like objects.